# After cpu time hits 8128 seconds my calculations stops

Tags: linux, math, calculator

I'm new to Linux and for my bachelor thesis I'm using it in order to calculate properties of materials in physics, therefore heavy calculations are involved. I've noticed that whenever Cpu time hits 8128 second ALL of my calculations are shut down and the code is like this:

- pw.x is the program that takes an input file in order to start calculations (diaginalize matrices , find eigenvalues, stuff like  that);
- Example.in is the input file for instance ;
- The program gives me back Example.out

The line of code in terminal is :

```
mpirun.openmpi -np 8 pw.x < Example.in > Example.out $
```

And when I type:

```
tail -f Example.out
```

to see my progress I can see that the program gives me back the time spent by the CPU in doing calculations.

When this time hits 8162 seconds everything stops, even if I press via terminal "top" I cannot see the pw.x programme running :(

Can you please help me?

Comment: What executable?

Comment: I'm using Quantum Espresso and in order to execute a file, for example the file Example.in , I need to feed it to a program named pw.x like this: pw.x < Example.in > Example.out.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659)?

Comment: Done. I do not know how tom provide an mcve because you need to download Quantum Espresso in order to get that pw.x program. I was thinking that maybe my computer is set to not run code more than 8000 seconds but I do not know if it is reasonable.

Comment: It's close enough to 8192 (2¹³) that it could be a resource limit set by your system's administrators. There's no reason why this limit should exist on a personal computer, though

Comment: I'm not using my PC but rather I'm connected to my college via VPN and using their processor.

Comment: 8128 is binary 1111111000000 (127 * 64), and is over two hours. I suspect a shared college resource might reasonably limit one remote process to that kind of limit. Can you run `ulimit -a` on that system and post the value for "cpu time"?

Comment: It states unlimited, I'm confused